# Use of the V notch

Tags: knives

I'm translating a book on bushcraft in English. There is a passage about the V notch that I am having a hard time understanding. It reads,

> This notch helps lock a piece of cordage to the desired area of a toggle. It can also be used on a larger scale to keep material that is stacked from moving if the diameter of the notch is equal to the stacked material or if the piece of wood to be used in conjunction with this one is notched in the same fashion.

I can't picture the notch being used as described in my head.

Answer (score 15):

Think of felling a tree with a hatchet or axe. The V-shaped 'incision' is a (rather rough) oversized V-notch.

On this picture, the notches on the lower side of the logs are  v-notches; an illustration of stacking with v-notches.

[image]

Now, if you have a (round) stick and with your knife carve or baton a v-notch, the diameter goes down where the notch is, and so a piece of cordage tied tightly at the notch cannot slide along the length of the stick - it is locked.

Happy translating :)